# How do I kill http hung connections?

Tags: python, http, mechanize, urllib2

I'm working on a script to crawling some interesting web pages for later research and it's programmed in a multi-threaded way. The problem I noticed is that no matter what library I use, for example `mechanize` or `urllib2` or `urllib`, there's always hung connections after several hours of running. I've tried with their separate timeout options as well as `socket.setdefaulttimeout` option, but nothing worked. It always ended up with 20 to 30 hung connections after two to three hours.

This bugs me a lot. Is there a better way to solve this problem? How do I kill these connections?